# Using Fetch API, how do I access JSON data when handling errors

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Our API server returns JSON data with error responses. I could not find a standard way of handling JSON data on error handling methods. my current solution is this. It is working, but I want to handle errors in catch() method not in then();

```js
let url = 'http://localhost:8080';
    let data = {'field': 'value'};
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json'        
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status == 400) {
          return res.json();
        } else if (!res.ok) {
          throw (res);
        } else {
          return res.json();
        }
      }).then(data => {
        if (data.status == 400) {
          throw (data);
        }
        return (data);
      }).catch(err => {
        if (err.status == 400) {
          throw this.handleError(err); 
        } else {
          throw new Error(`HTTP Error ${err.status}`);
        }
      });
```

this is an example of JSON response from server.

```js
{
    "parameters": {
        "type": {
            "isEmpty": "Field is required and cannot be empty"
        },
        "from": {
            "isEmpty": "Field is required and cannot be empty"
        },
        "to": {
            "isEmpty": "Field is required and cannot be empty"
        }
    },
    "title": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "/api/doc/invalid-parameter",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Invalid parameter"
}
```

Comment: oh ... so the JSON includes the status ... then it's easy if the status in JSON is always the same as the response status - `return Promise.reject(res.json())` if res.status == 400

Comment: It only returns JSON for a 400 response?

Comment: No this is just an example. It returns JSON for other error types. I will expand the code to handle them.

Comment: But you're saying you accept json, so I assume it returns json for successful responses too?

Comment: this code is included in a function. it returns this fetch promise. so you add another .then() to handle resolved data.

Comment: return Promise.reject(res.json()); works but in catch method, it is received as Promise not data.

Comment: yeah, sorry, it's `return res.json().then(x => Promise.reject(x));`

Comment: Yes, this works. It passes json data directly to catch method. If it were an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a thin wrapper around fetch which throws on >= 400 responses with parsed body else parses successful responses.

```
function parse(res) {
  const contentType = res.headers.get('Content-Type') || '';
  const isJson = contentType.includes('application/json');
  return isJson ? res.json() : res;
}

async function throwOnError(res) {
  if (res.status >= 400) {
    const err = new Error(res.statusText || 'Internal Server Error');
    err.status = res.status;
    const parsedRes = await parse(res);
    err.body = parsedRes;
    throw err;
  }

  return res;
}

async function fetchWrapper({ method, url, data, headers }) {
  const combinedHeaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  };

  if (headers) {
    Object.assign(combinedHeaders, headers);
  }

  const options = {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    mode: 'cors',
    method,
    headers: combinedHeaders,
  };

  if (data) {
    options.body = JSON.stringify(data);
  }

  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(throwOnError)
    .then(parse);
}

const queryParams = (params) =>
  Object.keys(params)
    .filter(k => params[k] !== null && typeof params[k] !== 'undefined')
    .map(k => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(params[k])}`)
    .join('&');

export const appendUrlParams = (url, params) => (params ? `${url}?${queryParams(params)}` : url);

export const $get = (url, params, { ...options }) =>
  fetchWrapper({ method: 'GET', url: appendUrlParams(url, params), ...options });

export const $del = (url, params, { ...options }) =>
  fetchWrapper({ method: 'DELETE', url: appendUrlParams(url, params), ...options });

export const $post = (url, data, { ...options }) =>
  fetchWrapper({ method: 'POST', url, data, ...options });

export const $put = (url, data, { ...options }) =>
  fetchWrapper({ method: 'PUT', url, data, ...options });
```

e.g.

```
async function fetchSomething() {
  try {
    const res = await $get('someurl');
    // Do something with successful `res`.
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    // err.status -> the status of the response
    // err.body -> the body of the response
  }
}
```

Or use then/catch if that's your preference.

Comment: thanks. I was expecting a simpler solution. In comments section this is solved. I was insisting on returning promises. May be a more elegant solution would be wrapping fetch in an async function.